# Get value of hidden row into javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, arrays, client-side

I have a grid column, of which, row X is hidden. I want to pick the values of each column's row x, perform some calculations at client side and display it in row y(through client side code).

I am not able to pick values from hidden field in client side.

Is there a way I can put those values in a client side array using javascript code, and use it for my calculations. Also when page posts back, the array should get updated with latest values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var span = document.all("FpSpread1_colFooter");
            span.firstChild.rows(2).style.display = 'none';

I have hidden the row at client side, which solved the problem of getting data from server-side.

Answer (score 2):

```
var value= document.getElementById("hiddenId").value;
```

hiddenId is the id  for the hidden element. Then you can use the value as you want in the client side.

Comment: I have a grid, which has 4 footer rows, out of which one footer row is hidden. How do i pick up that particular hidden row elements ?

Comment: for that hidden element add an attribute called id="hiddenId". inside javascript get that hidden element value.

Comment: Please consider the scenario that I cannot name that row. So how can I put those values into array ?

Comment: I am setting my row invisible with following code. I need all row values in client side. `FpSpread1.ActiveSheetView.ColumnFooter.Rows(1).Visible = False`

Comment: then you have to go with the html dom stucture to get that elements.